# Merge rows from one dataframe that do not match specific columns in another dataframe Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes and want to merge all the rows from one dataframe that do not have a set of matching columns to another dataframe. Below is an example:

```
import pandas

df_1 = pandas.DataFrame({"question":["ABC", "ABC", "EFG", "EFG"],
                         "answer":["abc", "bcd", "efg", "fgh"],
                         "grade":[ "A", "B", "F", "A"],
                         "system":[2,1,1,2]})

df_2 = pandas.DataFrame({"question":["ABC", "ABC", "EFG", "EFG"],
                         "answer":["abc", "jkl", "efg", "qrs"]})

print(f"df_1:\n{df_1}")
print(f"\ndf_2:\n{df_2}")


# <---console output-->

df_1:
  question answer grade  system
0      ABC    abc     A       2
1      ABC    bcd     B       1
2      EFG    efg     F       1
3      EFG    fgh     A       2

df_2:
  question answer
0      ABC    abc
1      ABC    jkl
2      EFG    efg
3      EFG    qrs
```

How do I append rows of `df_2` to `df_1` if `df_2['question', 'answer']` is not in `df_1`?

Desired result:

```
question    answer    grade    system
ABC         abc       A        2
ABC         bcd       B        1
EFG         efg       F        1
EFG         fgh       A        2
ABC         jkl       NaN      NaN
EFG         qrs       NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an `outer` join:

```
df_1.merge(df_2, how = "outer")
```

[image]