# In spark dataframe add columns to from one df to another without creating combination of matching rows

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

My data frames are like the following:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "a"), (1, "b"), (1, "c")], ("col1", "col2"))

        +----+----+
        |col1|col2|
        +----+----+
        |   1|   a|
        |   1|   b|
        |   1|   c|
        +----+----+
        
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "k1"), (1, "k2"), (1, "k3"),(1,"k4")], ("col1", "col3"))

        +----+----+
        |col1|col3|
        +----+----+
        |   1|  k1|
        |   1|  k2|
        |   1|  k3|
        |   1|  k4|
        +----+----+
```

I want to generate

```
df3 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "a", "k1"), (1, "b", "k2"), (1, "c", "k3"),(1, None, "k4")], ("col1", "col2", "col3"))
```

i.e., desired output:

```
    +----+----+----+
    |col1|col2|col3|
    +----+----+----+
    |   1|   a|  k1|
    |   1|   b|  k2|
    |   1|   c|  k3|
    |   1|null|  k4|
    +----+----+----+
```

I tried `df1.join(df2, on='col1', how="leftouter")` and got:

```
    +----+----+----+
    |col1|col2|col3|
    +----+----+----+
    |   1|   a|  k4|
    |   1|   a|  k3|
    |   1|   a|  k2|
    |   1|   a|  k1|
    |   1|   b|  k4|
    |   1|   b|  k3|
    |   1|   b|  k2|
    |   1|   b|  k1|
    |   1|   c|  k4|
    |   1|   c|  k3|
    |   1|   c|  k2|
    |   1|   c|  k1|
    +----+----+----+
```

I looked into [Merge rows from one dataframe that do not match specific columns in another dataframe Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049490/merge-rows-from-one-dataframe-that-do-not-match-specific-columns-in-another-data) . This very nearly what I want. But, It is using pandas df. Im not sure if switching form spark df to pandas df to do just this operation is a good idea. Is there a native pysprak way of doing this?

Need help with the transformation that gives the desired output.

Comment: in joins, leftouter = left. try passing "outer" in your case if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new `rank` column representing order of your rows in your two dataframes using [`window`](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-window-functions/), join your two dataframes on your first column and this `rank` column and finally drop `rank` column, as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

window1 = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("col2")
window2 = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("col3")

ranked_df1 = df1.withColumn("rank", F.row_number().over(window1))
ranked_df2 = df2.withColumn("rank", F.row_number().over(window2))

result_df = ranked_df1.join(
    ranked_df2, 
    on=['col1', 'rank'], 
    how='full_outer'
).drop('rank')
```

With `df1` and `df2` dataframes defined as in your question, you get the following `result_df` dataframe:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |a   |k1  |
|1   |b   |k2  |
|1   |c   |k3  |
|1   |null|k4  |
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my question and making it presentable. Your solution worked perfectly for me. Thanks a ton. The only change I made to your solution is to use `orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id`)` in the window function and created a single `window` definition that I reused. something like 
`window = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id().asc())
ranked_df1 = df_pages.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window))
ranked_df2 = df_critical_issues.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window))`